# Which street should we take a stroll down to get to the lake from the Thompson Hotel?

Tags: toronto

So I'm at the Thompson Hotel and plan on visiting the Ripley's Aquarium today if a route neat there is better. I was looking at Google Maps and I noticed the lake is nearby. There are many streets to walk down south but which street is not blocked off to pedestrians and actually leads near the lake with an interesting place to hangout or a good view to walk around in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bathurst Street, which your hotel sits at the corner of, has wide sidewalks on both sides of the street, all the way to the lakeshore.

When you reach Queens Quay West you can then connect with the Waterfront Trail, and follow it and connecting trails around the lake. Turn right (west) for a comparatively less commercial view of the lake, ending at around Humber Bay Park, and left (east) to view ports, docks, marinas, etc., ending around Beaches Park, or to take the Hanlan's Point ferry over to Toronto Islands. Either direction will take you out 8-10 km.

And if you're tired out from your walk to Humber Bay Park, go back up to Lake Shore Blvd and take the 301 bus or 501 streetcar ($3, exact cash) east to Bathurst Street, and you'll be about four blocks from your hotel.

Comment: I notice a lot of bugs flying around (unusally large amount)  around Bathurst & King too. That normal this time of year?  Is there tons of insects near the lake area? Are there tables & benches or places to eat by the lake?

Comment: @verve It's almost summer and that means insects anywhere you go, but it's a bit early in the season for large clouds of them. The weather has been unusually warm lately though. If you follow the trails west toward Humber Bay Park, you will cross through several parks and should have no trouble finding places to sit down and eat in most of them.

Comment: I asked the concierge and he said it might about some construction around Wesllesley so normally is it pretty bad otherwise because it's near the lake?  Never seen this much around Yonge and Bloor area at all. Feels creepy lol. There is like a zillion on the outside of the window. Hope they don't bite..

Comment: I'm not in Toronto right now so I can't easily pop down to get a look at the insect swarms myself. :)

Comment: :-) !!  Of course!  but if it's a regular thing in general I would not stay here again in the area.

Comment: @verve Ontario has had record breaking heat lately. So I think it's mostly to do with that. But you'll have fewer flying insects down by the lakefront, simply because it is a lake and insects can't easily live on a lake. It's anyone's guess what you'll find in the parks.

Comment: It looks we will walking after the aquarium.  What's the shortcut for pedestrians to the lake from Bremner Blvd? Cause sometimes I explore and end up at dead ends. It the lake area lit for night time fun?

Comment: At the aquarium you're on the very edge of the [PATH](http://www1.toronto.ca/wps/portal/contentonly?vgnextoid=f537b454b35a2410VgnVCM10000071d60f89RCRD&vgnextchannel=04708b7a29891410VgnVCM10000071d60f89RCRD) underground network, but taking it to the lakefront will take you further east. If you decided to walk that way anyway, then by all means; if you mean to follow the lakeshore west, I'd just follow Lower Simcoe Street down to the waterfront.